# Loading data from MySQL to use in D3 for creating line graph

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, django, d3.js

Actually I want to use D3 for creating graph for data visualization . My data resides in MySQL data base which I interact through python/django . I need to create D3 graphs using this data. I found two approach to do the same .

1. Create an arrays of dict having x and y coordinates and use the same to create graphs
2. Create a csv or tsv file on run time containing the data and use the same

My question is there any better way to achieve the same ? Above of the two approaches which one is better in terms of runtime and why ?

It would be great if you could point me to some worked out examples or tutorials

Comment: Regarding the runtime: implement both, then compare their runtime and you will see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are able to load data from your mysql database, in any case you will get it client-side in an object (array, map, whatever).

So there is no point writing a csv file from that to then extract the same data again.

You can do something like that:

```js
mysql.load("whatever",function(err, yourData){
  if(err) return err;
  
  d3.select(".somechart").selectAll(".someclass#someid")
    .data(yourData) // Feed data to your selection
    .enter() // enter the selection to modify it
    .append(".someclass#someid") // append some more elements to your selection
    // change attribute of each new element of the selection using yourData
    .attr("someattribute",function(d,i){ 
      // i is the index of the element in the selection
      // d is equivalent to yourData[i]
      // if yourData is an array of {x,y} then
      return d.x;
    }
    .attr("someOtherAttribute",function(d,i){
      return d.y;
    }
  
  });
}
```

I suggest you have a look at (at least) [this d3js tutorial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials), it will help you grasp how to work with d3 better.

Comment: thanks  I am trying to create var data like this var data = [
  { % for text in timecountgrp %}
   { x :{{text.date}} , y :{{text.count}}, },   {% endfor%} ]; This part is throwing error

   
 ];

Comment: I have strictly no idea of what this code does, sorry but I don't know your code. If my answer helped you for the D3 part, but you still have issues on getting the data from mysql, accept my answer and post a new question focused on that. (or search for existing ones).